# jbehave stdout output in wrong format on temcity

Tags: console, teamcity, stdout, jbehave

I'm using Jbehave , while I'm executing the tests locally (maven / IDE) the console output looks fine :

[image]

The console output on teamcity looks like :

[image]

And the output configuration in Jbehave configuration file looks like :

```
@Override
public Configuration configuration(){
    return new MostUsefulConfiguration().useStoryLoader(
            new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass())).useStoryReporterBuilder(
            new StoryReporterBuilder().withDefaultFormats().withFormats(
                    Format.TXT, Format.HTML, Format.ANSI_CONSOLE, Format.XML));
}
```

Any idea why the output in teamcity is "broken"

Answer (score 0):

I have no issues with this

```
    @Override
    public Configuration configuration(){
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration().useStoryLoader(
                new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass())).useStoryReporterBuilder(
                new StoryReporterBuilder().withFormats(Format.HTML, Format.CONSOLE));
    }
```

Html you'll find as resource files ane console will print to std out (build log on TC)